# Is it possible to separate html/js artifacts from Java web application, to speed up UI deployments?

Tags: javascript, java, maven

I primarily work on UI, but the project is a Java web project built with Maven. The build/deploy cycle takes about 5+ minutes to get it up and running on WebLogic, and I'd really like to be able to separate the HTML/JS from the Java, into separate build artifacts, mostly to speed up the development process, and also so I can use tools like npm and webpack to do my UI builds, and not have to rebuild and deploy the Java/Server side every time I build the UI.

My question is, can this be done? Is there a better way to design Java web applications to speed up UI coding? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you're using a server side technology like Spring MVC or client side like Angular.  Build, deploy, and startup are different things.

5 minutes isn't so bad if you're running JUnit tests.

Why not use something like Fiddler?  Use it as a mock to stand in for WebLogic for UI developers.  You can have it return a custom response for any request you can send to it.

You just have to agree on the interface XML or JSON or HTTP before you start.  You should already be doing that with your server side developers.  As long as everyone sticks to the contract it'll work when you integrate together.